# Pass variable into collection(collectionName).doc(docName)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a cloud firestore function. The last step I need for now is using the userId to retrieve a document.

Here I get the userId
const **userId** = snap.data().userId; <<< THIS WORKS
console.log('A new transaction has been added');

Here I want insert the value from userId to retrieve the correct document.

```
const deviceDoc = db.collection('device').doc(**userId**); <<< THIS IS THE PROBLEM

const deviceData = await deviceDoc.get();
const deviceToken = deviceData.data().token;
```

I don't know how to use the variable, **userId**, to insert the value into the .doc(**userId**) to get the data.

If userId = 12345 I want the line to look like this:

```
const deviceDoc = db.collection('device').doc('12345');
```

I have tried .doc('userId'), .doc('${userId}'), as well as other things. None of these work.

How do I do this?

Comment: `db.collection('device').doc(userId)` should work. What happens when you use that?

Comment: I think it is working. However, now I need to extract the data from "deviceDoc". So far, I have tried these 2 lines of code but neither work:    const deviceData = await deviceDoc.token.get;  
        const deviceId = await deviceDoc.data().deviceToken;

Comment: Here is the error in the log:  onTrxnCreate
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

As Puf has responded, you can simply use doc(userId).  The rest of your code looks fine, so maybe the document you are getting doesn't exist.  Try the following:

```
const deviceRef = db.collection('device').doc(userId);
// you can shorten this to >> const deviceRef = db.doc(`device/${userId}`);

try {
  const deviceDoc = await deviceRef.get();
  if (!deviceDoc.exists) {
    console.log(`The document for user ${userID} does not exist`);
  } else {
    const {token} = deviceDoc.data();
    console.log('The token is:', token);
  }
}
catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```